# Redirecting willTransitionTo in react-router 2.4.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently using `"react-router": "^2.4.0"` on my chat application  and confused on how to redirect when there is no user. I don't think **redirect** works in `"^2.4.0"` .

Should I use `onEnter` hooks on my **chat** path?

**Something like this:**

```
 <Route path="chat" component={Chat} onEnter={Chat.willTransitionTo}/>
```

**routes.js**

```
 <Route path="/" component={App} >
    <IndexRoute component={Chat} />
    <Route path="chat" component={Chat} />
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
 </Route>
```

**Chat.jsx**

```
static willTransitionTo(transition){
  var state = ChatStore.getState();
  if(!state.user){
    transition.redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by using `setRouteLeaveHook` as it says here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md

> return false to prevent a transition w/o prompting the user

However, they forget to mention that the hook should be unregistered as well, see [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/6eeb7ad358f987520f5b519e48bdd31f725cbade/modules/RouterUtils.js) and [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/6eeb7ad358f987520f5b519e48bdd31f725cbade/modules/createTransitionManager.js#L188).

We can use this to implement our own solution as follows:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const {route} = this.props;
    const {router} = this.context;

    this.unregisterLeaveHook = router.setRouteLeaveHook(
      route,
      this.routerWillLeave.bind(this)
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unregisterLeaveHook();
  }

  routerWillLeave() {
    // return false to prevent a transition w/o prompting the user,
    // or return a string to allow the user to decide:
    if (!this.state.isSaved) {
      return 'Your work is not saved! Are you sure you want to leave?'
    }
  }
  ...
}

YourComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: routerShape
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a spelling error:

```
tansition.redirect('/login');
```

Should be:

```
transition.redirect('/login');
```

You should also check the auth-flow example of react-router: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Comment: And seems like willTransitionTo was deprecated already in 1.0 in favor of onEnter: github.com/reactjs/react-router/releases?after=v1.0.2