# willTransitionFrom replacement in react-router 3

Tags: react-router

Is there a replacement mechanism for `willTransitionFrom` in react-router 3? I'm following an online training that uses an older recat version and they used `willTransitionFrom` to do pre-transition checks (such as making sure a form was saved before leaving it).

Comment: I am guessing I am following the same training. I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975803/redirecting-willtransitionto-in-react-router-2-4-0